# VBA iterate through variant which has 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

Was searching for a while, but cannot find a proper answer. I working on a variant and I used a solution provided below:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/305870-eliminate-duplicated-visual-basic-applications-array.html

So what I have is basically a variant which then beeing redimed without duplicates. It works fine if you use just one column from sheet so the variant variable has only 1 column as well.

The data I'm working on needs to be checked for 2 columns, while in the for each loop I would like to refer only to 2nd column:

```
    Dim mgNames As Variant
    Range(Cells(1, "I"), Cells(Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row, "J")).Select
    mgNames = Selection
Dim myCollection As New Collection
Dim temp As Variant
On Error Resume Next
For Each temp In mgNames
    myCollection.Add Item:=temp, Key:=temp
Next temp
On Error GoTo 0
ReDim mgNames(1 To myCollection.Count)
For temp = 1 To myCollection.Count
    mgNames(temp) = myCollection(temp)
Next temp
```

so in part *For Each temp In mgNames* code takes each value in variant, ex mgnames(1,1) then mgnames(1,2) and so on. I would like to iterate this only for 2nd column, so from (1,2) (2,2), (3,2)...

If anyone is able to help with this it would be great

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to loop through the array with `For Each`, you can use a normal `For`, as in

```
Dim i As Long
...
For i = LBound(mgNames,1) To Ubound(mgNames,1)
    myCollection.Add Item:=mgNames(i,2), Key:=mgNames(i,2)
Next i
...
```

Comment: That's perfect, I appreciate quick response! :) Lukasz

Comment: @user3181697 - no problem, glad to help. If you find an answer satisfying please consider marking it as the accepted answer.